# Infinite Series Convergence using comparison test

Tags: convergence-divergence

I am trying to use the comparison test to determine whether the following infinite series converges.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+2n-1}}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+2n-1}} $$

Is there a way to show that $1/\sqrt{n^3}$ converges? I used Wolfram|Alpha and it told me it does.

Comment: Compare it with the integral, for example.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't use the integral test. It does converge.

Comment: Compare $n^2$ and $n^{3/2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The $p$-series theorem says
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n^p} < \infty$$
iff $p > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The power of the denominator is above 1, so it converges. If my memory serves me correctly, it is only necessary to look at the highest-power term (in this case $n^3$). We know that $\sqrt{n^3} = n^{3/2}$, which grows faster than n... Remember, n is the boundary - a higher order denominator will converge, while a lower order denominator will diverge.